# Using "display:block" but can't keep my image on the same horizontal plane as the text

Tags: html, css, block, display

I would like to keep a CSS3 arrow on the same horizontal plane as some text.  In other words, I would like all this to stay on the same horizontal plane ...

```
    <div style="display:block">
        <div id="downArrow" class="downArrow arrow"></div>
    - 1.5780377548310014 / -0.01013426671732404 % 
    </div>
```

I thought "display:block" would do the trick but apparently not -- https://jsfiddle.net/6m7vegwc/ .  Only problem is the CSS for the arrow requires an "after"

```
.downArrow:after {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
    linear-gradient(-120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
    linear-gradient(to top, #ccc, #000);
}
```

and I think this is throwing things off.  Anyway, how can I keep my arrow on the same horizontal plane as the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix would be to make them all display inline-block.

```css
#oneDayChange > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.arrow:after {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
}

.upArrow:after {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #000);
}

.downArrow:after {
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(-120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(to top, #ccc, #000);
}
```

```html
<div id="oneDayChange">
  One day change
  <div>
    <div id="downArrow" class="downArrow arrow"></div>
    - 1.5780377548310014 / -0.01013426671732404 %
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for display:inline alternatively use a  instead of a  as inline is its normal state.

Here is a guide that explains it in full https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `display: flex`

```
<div id="oneDayChange">
        ...
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;">
        ...
</div>
```

Read more about flexbox (one of the better css innovations in recent years) [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Why use "flex" instead of "inline," as suggested by others?

Comment: `flex` is nice if you also want to have your content aligned vertically. It gives you a lot more power. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great article about flexbox.

Comment: @Dave there are a few reasons, one of which is just a stylistic choice. Another is that flexbox can honestly be adapted to solve 80-90% of layout issues (in my experience), and so I've chosen to just master `flex` so my code is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `display: inline` but you could simplify your example by just swapping the `<div>`s against `<span>`s because `<span>` tags are by default `display: inline`

If you want to have everything more steady and centered, you can also use `display: flex` which takes it's children and spreads them horizontally and stretches them vertically by default.

```css
#oneDayChange {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* align to the left */
  align-items: center; /* center content vertically */
}


.arrow:after {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'';
}

.upArrow:after {
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
            linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
            linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #000);
}

.downArrow:after {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
    linear-gradient(-120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
    linear-gradient(to top, #ccc, #000);
}
```

```html
<div id="oneDayChange">
  One day change 
  <span id="downArrow" class="downArrow arrow"></span>
  - 1.5780377548310014 / -0.01013426671732404 % 
</div>
```